# Mobile Tel link displaying in black, when all styles are set to white with !important

Tags: html, css

I have looked around for the answer and a close article was this: [HTML links not clickable on mobile, but are clickable on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003865/html-links-not-clickable-on-mobile-but-are-clickable-on-desktop)

On my site: https://venueswl.com/

In the footer (only on an actual mobile device) the mobile and email links are black. However across desktop and laptop, these links are white and correctly working.

I can't see any blinding errors either using the inspect element on Google.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add relevant code of what you have already tried

Comment: I assume you're talking about the phone numbers on the footer. Viewing the website through Chrome's device viewer unfortunately does not reproduce the problem, however viewing it directly on my phone _does_ reproduce it. Have you tried applying inline style rules directly on the phone numbers to override the default OS styling?

Comment: No I haven't, can I apply this directly to WordPress? @Epicular

Comment: <p style= font-size: 15px; font-weight: 500;">Tel <a style="color: #ffffff !important;">+44 (0)20 8254 4800</a>
Fax +44 (0)20 8254 4801
Skypewhite.light.sw19</p>

Comment: If that's the code you're using now and the phone numbers are still appearing black, then I'd take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios).

Comment: Ok so I am looking at this answer: a[href^="tel"] {
  color: inherit; /* Inherit text color of parent element. */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline. */
  /* Additional css `propery: value;` pairs here */
}

This website is on a theme, can I apply this to the theme css file?

Comment: That is a CSS rule, so yes, you would be able to. But it won't work unless the anchor's `href` value starts with `tel`. Also it'll continue to have no effect if you leave the `color: #ffffff !important` attribute. But if the `!important` still doesn't work, then I have no idea what CSS trick would. I gotta imagine that WP is still messing with the style somehow (I don't use WP so I wouldn't know).

Comment: Ok so I have put this now: <p style="color: #ffffff font-size: 15px; font-weight: 500;">Tel <a>+44 (0)20 8254 4800</a>
Fax +44 (0)20 8254 4801
Skypewhite.light.sw19</p>

I have also applied this to the theme itself: a[href^="tel"] {
  color: #fff !important; 
  text-decoration: none; 
 
}